# How to improve Testing Accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, decision-tree, training-data

I am new to Machine learning ! I am currently using Decision Tree Classifier for my text classification problem,as my model and I am getting training accuracy as 98% but testing accuracy as 48% only , how to improve the testing accuracy ?

So , basically this is a text classification , so I used count vectorizer to convert it into numerical format and later I splitted data and I trained the model , the code looks like below :-

```
combined_transformer = CountVectorizer( )
X = combined_transformer.fit_transform(data_frame['Input Text'])

Y = data_frame['Target']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train , X_test , Y_train , Y_test = train_test_split( X , Y , test_size = 0.1 , shuffle = True , random_state = 102 , stratify = Y)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train , Y_train)

#Accuracy
p = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(X_test , p) #Which gives me only 48%
```

Comment: You have not provided the complete `code`, how will  user suggest any changes, meanwhile check any tutorial like to get started https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/improve-machine-learning-results/

Comment: You shouldn't be measuring the accuracy of the model on the training split of the dataset.

Comment: Your training data might be biased. Try shuffling the training and testing data, or try adding more training data.

Comment: How do you split your data into train and test? You need to provide more code and information. Either your test set is not representative or you are overfitting.

Comment: @Sauron Uploaded the code !

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Uploaded the code !

Comment: @ConorEgan Then on what basis one should measure their model's performance ?

Comment: Do not ask questions about improving model performance, it is off-topic, people can only guess, as what you are doing is basically research.

Comment: @Chandra measure accuracy against the test split of the dataset, which is what you are doing in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is a great question. First, change test size from 0.1 to at least 0.2 `test_size=0.2`. If your data set is greater than 10k rows you can keep test size 0.1, but if it is under 1k rows than you surely want to make test size ~0.3 In your case, your model is over fitting. It means that your training data set is not good or you did not fine-tune hyper parameters of your model. To fine tune hyper parameters try to use grid search algorithm. Here is an example

```
criterion_range = ['gini', 'entropy']
splitter_range = ['best', 'random']
max_depth_range = list(range(1, 12, 1))  # from 1 to 12, step 1
min_samples_split_range = list(range(2, 21, 2))  # from 2 to 20, step 2
min_samples_leaf_range = list(range(1, 11))  # from 1 to 10, step 1

# Define hyperparameter for grid search
param_grid = {
    'criterion': criterion_range,
    'splitter': splitter_range,
    'max_depth': max_depth_range,
    'min_samples_split': min_samples_split_range,
    'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf_range
} # you can modify it and increase number of hyper parameters

# Create the GridSearchCV object
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,
                           cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, scoring='accuracy') # scoring can be changed same as cv, n_jobs and verbose

# Grid search your model
grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)

best_params = grid_search.best_params
print(f"Best hyperparameters: {best_params}")
```

You also can save all grid search results in csv in order to analyzes results. From that csv you can calculate F1-score for each of a row. Keep in mind, that if your initial training did take more than 2 minutes, you are looking for 2-5 h of finding those hyper parameters. So, be mindful with step size and how many hyper parameters you use. I hope it did help. Also, for more information refer to official documents [a link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Last but not least, do not take those comments harshly. They simply do not know better.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution ! I will try it for sure !!

Comment: Note that OP is using a decision tree classifier, not a random forest. The n_estimators parameter doesn't do anything unless you're using a RandomForestClassifier. I do think that a random forest would help with overfit, though.

Comment: Please do not answer obviously off-topic questions, see here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme/

Comment: @Chandra I did edit it. and included a few links same as some suggestions

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I understand your concerns. Nevertheless, he clearly stated that he is new to ML which means that the only non-bias answer is grid search. Do not see an issue with that as grid search is straight forward. This question is not about data set or anything our of this world. If he did include a script with grid search and asked this question than yes. I would agree with your point. I will take your guide line into consideration.

Comment: Maybe I need to say this clearly, improving the performance of a ML model is not a programming problem, and Stack Overflow is only a programming site, so the question is off-topic. Being new to ML does not change that and is irrelevant. There are other sites that fit much better like ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ok, it make sense. Than we probably should close this question as off-topic